# angular 2 , after ng build --prod , ui-router stop working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

Angular program working with node js server using (ng serve command). 
I want to use that code in a shared  Linux server, I am Build Command as below:

```
ng build --prod
```

I am compiling using Xammp but got an error:

> main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-app/dist/my-app'
>       Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-app/dist/my-app'
>           at t.noMatchError (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.selector (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at t.noMatchError (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.selector (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e._error (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at j (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>           at j (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>           at polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1
>           at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1)
>           at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>           at t.runTask (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>           at d (polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js:1)
>       ue @ main.7f9abf101b04a0e0134f.js:1

Please help me, with me with what necessary steps is for compiling the Angular 2+ code and using in Xammp/server directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try this*

ng build --base-href=\yourUrl\ --prod

Comment: All file is rendering properly but it throwing an error while routing.   `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'`

Comment: Did you do this in your index.html ?

<base href="/">

Comment: the URL is given in `code' --base-href `code'  that is present in index.html base href